# How to validate PFX with public-key privacy/integrity mode

Tags: ssl, pfx, pkcs#12

I have a piece of embedded software generating P12/PFX formatted output data.

The PFX is **not** password protected, that means instead of using a password-derived encryption/mac key the data is encrypted with a public key and signed with my private key.

In [RFC7292 section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#section-3.1) this is called public-key privacy and integrity modes.

My question is, how can I validate the PFX I receive, e.g. using `openssl`? (I'm not restricted to use openssl, by the way I google'd around but could not find a way...)

I tried

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in test.pfx
```

but openssl requests a password, which is not applicable here. Did I miss any option to not being asked for a password?

Answer (score 12):

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in test.pfx -passin pass: -passout pass:
```

Alternatively, you can just use

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in test.pfx
```

and when it asks for Import Password or PEM Pass Phrase (and you didn't use any while generating the pfx file), just press Enter.

Answer (score 2):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keyStoreWithoutPW.p12 -info -passin pass: -passout pass:
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but I got some error trying what you suggested with my test.pfx:

Comment: Mac verify error: invalid password?  
18000:error:2307E06C:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_verify_mac:mac absent:p12_mutl.c:119:  
18000:error:2307E06C:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_verify_mac:mac absent:p12_mutl.c:119:

Comment: I get the same error for a .p12 file which has a **NON**-empty password. Are you sure there is no password in your test.pfx ? You can validate this with _openssl pkcs12 -info -in test.pfx_

Comment: Can you provide the test.pfx?