# An error occurred during encode or decode operation. During Certificate Import in My Cert Store using C# code from a pfx

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I'm getting the following exception while importing a `.pfx` into My Cert Store in Windows from C# code. I was able to install it from the pfx directly but getting exception while trying to import it from code.

Error:

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: An error occurred during encode or decode operation.

Code:

```
public void Test01()
{
    var filePath = "C:\\cert.pfx"
    var cert01 = new X509Certificate2(filePath, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

    using var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cert01);
}
```

Could anyone let me know what all possible issues could be there while I am importing the cert. Thanks

Expectation was a successful import once we create an object of `X509Certificate2`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide the full exception stack.

Comment: Since you have a coding error, the first item is to verify the PFX. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46790280/8016720) might help. Next list the contents of the PFX. Is it a single certificate or a collection of certificates? The code is different `X509Certificate2Collection()`.